# BSc in Chemistry during PhD?

Tags: phd, bachelor, chemistry, neuroscience

I have a BSc in Psychology with a strong focus on neuroscience and am currently studying Molecular Neuroscience. Next year I want to start my PhD in molecular Neuroscience but I am really interested in basic Chemistry. The aim for me is to get a strong foundation in chemistry and become a more independent researcher in molecular neuroscience. Thus, I am searching for a way to study Chemistry without having to delay my PhD by another 3 years. I would like to get input on what options there are and what other people have done. Thanks a lot for any help and input!

Comment: Does "currently studying" mean you are in a masters program?

Comment: In the US, your PhD program will help you take an necessary undergraduate or graduate courses to pass your prelims.

Comment: If you have time, money, and energy, go for it. Prepare to drop one program, if you feel like you can't handle both at the same time. PhD is very time consuming.

Answer (score 3):

It's helpful to distinguish a degree (bachelors in chemistry in this case) from expertise in a field. A degree indicates some expertise in your major field, but it also indicates that you can manage all the requirements and expectations to achieve a degree. However, simply taking undergraduate courses (even auditing them) or self study will let you learn what you want/need to without the extraneous requirements that a degree entails (getting admitted to a program, taking courses outside your field or that you're not interested in, etc.).

If you are planning to get a PhD in neuroscience, getting a 2nd bachelors in chemistry isn't that important. You've already shown that you can earn a bachelors degree, what matters now is developing the chemistry expertise for the research you want to pursue. Get into a neuro PhD program, take some chemistry classes, establish collaborations with chemists, and learn as you go. Best of luck on your journey.

Comment: Thanks a lot that is very helpful advice!

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a bachelor's, some schools may not let you use scholarships/grants etc. to fund your next BSc in Chemistry. If this is not an issue then don't worry about it anyway.

However, it might be more worthwhile to try to find a PhD program (if you have not already chosen one) that will let you work in a strong chemistry/biochemistry research area. Many PhD programs, offer your masters degree upon completion of a year or two of your PhD program. If you can find one that lets you do this, you can design your PhD research to be both chemistry/biochemistry heavy and neuroscience heavy. This should be able to get you the chemistry background you want.

If this is not possible, during your PhD studies take as many chemistry classes as you can that even vaguely fit your project/field of study. If all else fails, there is always self-study with no degree awarded at the end.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the practical advice I will certainly take that into account!